# Convert dates from Stata to R

Tags: r, time, stata, as.date

I am having difficulty converting a vector of integers into dates.

I've imported a dataset from Stata using:

```
> dataire <- read.dta13("~/lcapm_ireland.dta", convert.factors = TRUE,
 generate.factors = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8", fromEncoding = NULL, 
convert.underscore = FALSE, missing.type = FALSE, convert.dates = TRUE, 
replace.strl = TRUE, add.rownames = FALSE)
```

My date variable is a monthly time series starting on January 2000 and formatted as "2000-Jan".

Similarly to R, Stata handles dates as integers but in the latter January 1960 is origin zero for monthly dates. Thus, when importing the dataset into R, I end up with a vector of dates of the form:

```
> c(478, 479, 480, ...)
```

In addition, my date variable is:

```
> class(datem)
[1] "Date"
```

How can I use `as.Date` or other functions to transform the time-series of integers in a monthly date variable formatted as `"%Y-%b"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't get exactly what you want. This is because
in R, dates with numeric form must include a day.

For successfully importing a Stata date in R, you first can convert the respective 
variable in Stata from a monthly to a date-time one:

```
clear
set obs 1

generate date = monthly("2000-Jan", "YM")

display %tmCCYY-Mon date
2000-Jan

display date
480

replace date = dofm(date)

display %tdCCYY-Mon date
2000-Jan

display date
14610

replace date = cofd(date) + tc(00:00:35)

display %tc date
01jan2000 00:01:40

display %15.0f date
1262304100352
```

Then in R you can do the following:

```
statadatetime <-  1262304100352

rdatetime <- as.POSIXct(statadatetime/1000, origin = "1960-01-01")
rdatetime
[1] "2000-01-01 02:01:40 EET"

typeof(rdatetime)
[1] "double"

rdate <- as.Date(rdatetime)
rdate
[1] "2000-01-01"

typeof(rdate)
[1] "double"
```

You can get the Year-(abbreviated) Month form you want with the following:

```
rdate = format(rdate,"%Y-%b")
[1] "2000-Jan"

typeof(rdate)
[1] "character"
```

However, as you can see, this will change the type of `rdate` holding
the date.

Trying to change it back you get:

```
rdate <- as.Date(rdate)
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler but you will get a date with day, 1990-03-01.

You have a column vector of integers, DATE_IN_MONTHS, that are months since the origin of time in Stata which is 1960-01-01. In R the origin of time is is 1970-01-01.

With package **lubridate** one simple changes the origin of time and then adds months:

```
db <- haven::read_dta('StataDatabase.dta') %>%
        dplyr::mutate(., DATE_IN_MONTHS = ymd("1960-01-01") + months(DATE_IN_MONTHS))
```

Now db$DATE_IN_MONTHS contains `c(1990-03-01, 1990-04-01, 1990-05-01,...)` where each element is a date in R.