# Convert dates from stata data to r

Tags: r

I have a data set that was created in Stata that looks like this:

```
Car Date
BMW 19057
SAAB 19169
Volvo 19295
```

I want to convert the dates from the Stata-format to R format (integer is fine). I found this post about it: [Convert dates from Stata to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672983/convert-dates-from-stata-to-r)

But I cannot use Stata to do this since I got the data files exported from Stata to csv. Is it possible to do it without using Stata?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Your printed code shows `Date` as an integer. What are you trying to do? Have you read in the .csv to R?

Comment: I have. I want to convert the date formate from stata to something like: 20200515

Comment: Okay, but you aren't saying what the date format currently is. Can you edit your question to have some data to use from the csv with `dput`? This will help me understand what the current dates look like, otherwise there is no way to know what you need. Above you have dates as integers too but there is no clear date pattern as far as I can tell?

Comment: So what does `19057` tell us exactly? Number of days since an origin (e.g. since January 2015). It helps if you give us an example of desired output that you want in R.

Comment: What would date of today look in your stata format?

Comment: I dont know more than that the csv file has the data `19057` where there should be a date on the form `ddmmyyyy`. Isn't possible to convert it from stata to R without knowing the origin?

Comment: According to Stata (https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-date-variables/), a date is *'the number of days from January 1, 1960"*. This suggests `as.Date(c(19057,19169,19295), origin = "1960-01-01")`.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Stat's [FAQ about date variables](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-date-variables/),

> *You can record dates anyway you want, but there is only one technique that Stata understands, called an elapsed date. An elapsed date is the number of days from January 1, 1960.*

From this, if your data is

```r
dat <- structure(list(Car = c("BMW", "SAAB", "Volvo"), Date = c(19057L, 
19169L, 19295L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Then do this:

```r
dat$Date2 <- as.Date(dat$Date, origin = "1960-01-01")
dat
#     Car  Date      Date2
# 1   BMW 19057 2012-03-05
# 2  SAAB 19169 2012-06-25
# 3 Volvo 19295 2012-10-29
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `as_date`

```
library(lubridate)
dat$Date2 <- as_date(dat$Date, origin = "1960-01-01")
dat$Date2
#[1] "2012-03-05" "2012-06-25" "2012-10-29"
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(Car = c("BMW", "SAAB", "Volvo"), Date = c(19057L, 
19169L, 19295L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```