# Dates in R imported from Stata

Tags: r

I am importing a dataset from Stata into R with monthly dates formatted as %tm (e.g. 2018m6, 2018m7, etc). When imported into Stata, I get the same variables as numbers (e.g. for 2018m6 I get 701 and for 2018m7 I get 702). Is this normal? Is R understanding they are dates properly or do I need to change the format?

Thank you very much,

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a previous answer on Stackoverflow regarding importing dates from Stata.  Give this a try: [Convert dates from Stata to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672983/convert-dates-from-stata-to-r)

Comment: Thank you very much! This code works perfectly. Sorry if my question is very basic but am a bit new to R, how do I then run a regression with the new date variable? this seems to create a new dataset and in my original dataset I still have the old variable with the numbers. Do I just change the variable from "date" (old name) to "dates_df"?

Comment: You can add a column to your original dataframe.  `og_df$dates_new <- new_list_of_dates` This assumes the number of rows in your original dataframe equals the number of dates in the new list.  Also, if you wouldn't mind, please flag my answer as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you again! But the problem is that I am using panel data so when I try your new code it tells me: "`Error: Assigned data "new_list_of_dates" must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 134495 rows.
x Assigned data has 28 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.`" - Is there a way to tell R to match the new dates with the old date variable? Thank you very much!

Comment: @maxjohnson, I adjusted the code so that it should work with your existing dataframe of data (assuming your data is in a dataframe).  It will split the old `Date` column into a `Year` and `Month` column and then overwrite the old `Date` column with the new `Date` format.  Replace `data` with your dataframe name and `Date` with your date column name.

Comment: Thank you! This creates a data variable but it still only has 28 rows and has deleted all the rest of my variables, is this normal? as you suggested I replaced "data" with "finaldata" (name of my dataframe) and "Date" with "date" (name of my date variable)

Comment: @maxjohnson, I updated the code based on you providing the dataframe and column names. give it try.

Comment: Thank you again. I tried this too but the problem is that my data frame finaldata just becomes a dataframe with three variables (date, year, month) and 28 rows (one for each month I am using). How could I attach this format to the existing column and keep all the rest of the data?

Comment: Weird. Which version of R are you using? Type `version` in the console to see. The code shouldn't replace any data.  The code should add `year` and `month` columns to your existing dataframe `finaldata` and only overwrite `date` with the new format.

Comment: I am using 4.0.2. The code I am running is as follows: `library(haven) /nextline
finaldata <- read_dta("~/Stata Datafiles/finaldata.dta")
/nextline
library(stringr)
/nextline
finaldata <- data.frame('date'=c('2018m6', (rest of dates in between), '2020m12'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
/nextline
finaldata[,c('Year','Month')] <- str_split_fixed(finaldata$date, pattern = 'm', n = 2)
/nextline
finaldata$date <- as.Date(paste(finaldata$Year, finaldata$Month, "01", sep = "-"))`

Comment: Actually I have taken out the command "finaldata <- data.frame('date'=c('2018m6',..., '2020m12'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)" as per the new code but then when I run the last command it tells me "Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format". Checking the data, the Year variable has taken the 701, 702 numbers and the month variable is empty.

Comment: Any help would be very very much appreciated

Comment: @maxjohnson, i added the `format` argument to the `as.Date()` function.  Hopefully that'll resolve the issue.  If not, you'll have to paste a sample of what is in `finaldata` prior to running the final line of code.

Comment: Thank you very much again, for some reason I keep having the same problem. When I upload the data, I have a variable "date" which is "701, 702, etc". When I split the date string on the m (first line of code in your answer) this creates two new variables: "Year" which is identical to "date" (701, 702, etc) and "Month" which is blank. If I paste the second line of code above, the "date" variable becomes "NA" and there is no change to the other two variables. I think the problem may be in the first line of code? because the year and month variables it creates do not reflect year and month.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you load in the data from Stata into R before you run any transformation code on the dates... how are the dates formated, (e.g. 2018m6 or 701)?

Comment: before I load the data from stata into R they are formatted 2018m6, after loading it they change to 701. If easier I could also change the format in Stata?

Comment: Yeah, the code I gave was trying to convert the 2018m6 to a date. The code above will not work on date values like 701. I found this specific problem in a previous answer, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672983/convert-dates-from-stata-to-r

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question: I did as suggested on Stata and in R I added the following commands: rdatetime <- as.POSIXct(finaldata$date/1000, origin = "1960-01-01") and
rdate <- as.Date(rdatetime). This creates a Large date with all the elements and is saved as "Value" in the environment. Is this how it is supposed to be? and how can I add this to my dataset?

Comment: I used "finaldata <- cbind(finaldata, rdate)" to merge the datasets and now it should be working. Thanks a lot for all your help